# What are the processes whose second moment equal their quadratic variation (like the Brownian motion)?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, quadratic-variation

If $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion, we know that

$$[B]_t=t=E[B_t^2]$$

where $[.]_t$ is the quadratic variation at time $t$.

Can we characterize all processes such that

$$ [X]_t=E[X_t^2]$$

If not, what are large classes of processes that have this property ?

Comment: Any continuous martingale $X_t$ started at 0 has $E[[X]_t] = E[X_t^2]$, so for continuous martingales, this just asks when the quadratic variation is deterministic.  I think it ought to follow from Levy's characterization that such a process $X$ must be a deterministic time change of Brownian motion.