# Continuous square integrable martingale with non-random quadratic variation.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

In a comment on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3599614/what-are-the-processes-whose-second-moment-equal-their-quadratic-variation-like) @NateEldredge postulates that if a martingale (continuous, square integrable and starting at $0$)
$M=(M_t)$ is such that 
$$E(M_t^2)=\langle M\rangle_t$$ i.e. the quadratic variation is non-random then it *"ought to follow from Levy's characterization that such a process $M$ must be a deterministic time change of Brownian motion."*

I think this is good enough to be a question itself hence if someone could explain me this in more detail it would be nice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually follows from the [Dambis, Dubins-Schwarz theorem](https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/lecture-23-time-changed-martingales-and-planar-brownian-motion/), i.e. if $\lim_{t\to\infty}\langle M\rangle_t=\infty$ a.s., then $M_t=B_{\langle M\rangle_t}$, where $B$ is a Brownian motion. So when the quadratic variation of $M$ is deterministic, it is a deterministic time change of a BM.

Comment: Even if $\lim_{t\to\infty}\langle M\rangle_t$ is finite, the time-changed process $X_s:=M_{b(s)}$   is a Brownian motion on $[0,\langle M\rangle_\infty)$, where $b(s):=\inf\{t: \langle M\rangle_t>s\}$. This follows from Lévy's theorem.